# Split string into several substrings in C

Tags: c, windows, char

I have a char that contains several HTTP headers. 
Now I want to split the headers and store each header into a char[] array, like

```
myheader[0] = "POST /index001.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:xxx  ...";   
myheader[1] = "POST /index002.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:xxx  ..."
```

Each header size is different, so I can't count bytes. I have no idea how to do that. strstr() only finds the first substring.

The buffer format is like this:

```
POST /index001.html HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
...
POST /index002.html HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
...
POST /index003.html HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
...
```

Can anyone help me with code plz?

Edit:

I wrote a function that extracts a substring from a buffer. But it can only deal with the first pair of "POST"s.
For example,

GetInBetween( "1234www567890rrr777wwwOUEJF99rrr", "www", "rrr") can only get "567890".

```
char * GetInBetween( char* buffer, char* start, char* end)
{
    char * subbuffer = NULL;
    subbuffer = strstr(buffer, startpoint);  

    int betweenLen = 0;
    if (subbuffer == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    betweenLen = strcspn(subbuffer, endpoint );   

    int sbLen=0;
    sbLen= strlen(subbuffer);   
    int spLen =0;
    spLen = strlen(startpoint);  

    int dataLen =0;
    dataLen = betweenLen - spLen;  

    char databuffer[1024];
    for (int i =0; i< dataLen; i++) 
    {
        databuffer[0+i] = subbuffer[4+i]; 
    }
    databuffer[dataLen] ='\0';
    int test = strlen(databuffer);

    return databuffer;
}
```

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: Make the question a bit more clear

Comment: I once wrote a split function `GetInBetween( char* buffer, char* start, char* end)`.  I used `strstr()` `strcspn()`. But this function can only deal with the first pair of "POST"s. I 've no idea how to deal the third and fourth and so on.

Comment: You said the headers are different lengths? I see headers sections that all look identical in length. Even if they're not they look separated by newlines how you've described it so you could try getline()

Comment: How are the headers separated? Normally after HTTP headers and before the content two newlines are sent. Do you get those newlines?

Comment: post the complete headers as is, it may contains useful information that you let it behind eg: a dot in a single line or double CrLf "\r\n\r\n"

Comment: @WernerHenze   Yes, I do get those newlines. But I was thinking what if the content contains some newlines too? Newlines shouldn't be the separator since they are too common. But "POST /index001.html HTTP/1.1" can hardly be found in content.

Comment: @MinKim Read the HTTP spec. The Header is followed by two new lines, the Content length is provided in the Header Content-length (?). If you must handle stored HTTP sessions that might have been closed in the middle of Transfer, then you Need to extend the file Format to add the real length of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your function to have some memory of earlier calls, like `strtok` does. Then you can call your function repeatedly in the same buffer to find any subsequent occurrences. As a sketch of such an approach (finish ot yourself):

```
char * GetInBetween( char* buffer, char* startstr, char* endstr)
{
    static char *lastbuf, *lastbufp, *laststartstr, *lastendstr;
    char * subbuffer = NULL;
    if (startstr==NULL || endstr==NULL) {
        if (lastbuf!=buffer) return NULL;    // not same buffer: error;
        if (lastbufp==NULL) return NULL;     // no previous match, so no next match
        subbuffer= strstr(lastbufp, laststartstr);
    }
    else
    {
        laststartstr= startstr;        // remember the parts to search in between
        lastendstr= endstr;
        lastbuf= buffer;
        subbuffer = strstr(buffer, startpoint); 
        lastbufp= NULL;                // no match yet to remember
    }
```